# SU* keys in plist files

Tags: plist

I've noticed that most applications that I use have common keys in their plist files that start with SU. Examples are:

```
SUHasLaunchedBefore
SULastCheckTime
SUScheduledCheckInterval
```

What does SU stand for? What do these keys mean? How do their values affect my preferences?

Comment: From which specific plist file is this? And can you add the relevant of the file directly, not just list the names.

Comment: @nohillside I’ve seen them (but most likely not limited to) menubar apps like Bartender, Hazel, Endurance, etc.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Sparkle

These keys are used by the [open source Sparkle framework](https://sparkle-project.org).

> Sparkle is an easy-to-use software update framework for macOS applications. It delivers updates using appcasting, a term used to refer to the practice of using RSS to distribute update information and release notes.

`SU` stands for Software Update. The project [publishes documentation](https://sparkle-project.org/documentation/customization/) for currently supported property list (plist) keys.